# Managing Wordpress Database (Adminer)

Tags: php, wordpress, adminer

Im new to wordpress and having difficulties in managing the database. I have installed "**Adminer**" plugin to manage the database. I already created a new table called "**usersupp_admin**". Now I also created a custom template that will connect to this database using PDO statements, the problem now is where can I get the host, dbname, user, and password? Here's the codes:

```
<?php

 $host   = "";
 $dbname = "";
 $user   = "";
 $pass   = "";

 $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname",$user,$pass);
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM usersupp_admin";
 $q   = $conn->query($sql) or die("failed!");
 $result = $q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
 $user_db=$result['username'];
 echo $user_db;
 ?>
```

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey You don't require to create connection once again if you do it once in theme.

Just simply have to add following code in your external file.

```
/* Short and sweet */
define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
require('../../../wp-blog-header.php');
?>
```

`wp-blog-header.php` is located at root of your theme. 
This file you have to include, After including you can access wordpress in any external template.

[Reference from](http://codex.wordpress.org/Integrating_WordPress_with_Your_Website)

You don't require that any type of connection, if you include this file once.
for example :

```
define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
require('./wp-blog-header.php');
header('HTTP/1.1 200 OK');
global $wpdb;

$rs = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM usersupp_admin", ARRAY_A); 

if (count($rs) > 0) {
    echo $username =  $rs['username'];
}
```

Comment: the problem is how can I connect to the database?

Comment: This file is used to connect wordpress database.Simply add code in external file, you will connect successfully with your db. Add code,and run any query in you file , you will get success.

Comment: where is your external file located in your theme ? Do one thing, find  wp-blog-header.php in your theme root, and include this file in your template ( at the start up of the page ) with proper path.

Comment: I'll try that. Moreover, I am using PDO statements. Where can I get the hostname, databasename, username, and password?